# Nx Workspace - How can I serve an angular project as https

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have an nx workspace with an angular project and a nestjs backend, it's all compiling and working fine. I have a requirement now to host the angular app locally using https for development, for this I would usually do:

`ng serve ui --ssl --ssl-key ./local-cert/localhost.key --ssl-cert ./local-cert/localhost.crt`

however with nx I want to run both the api and ui projects at the same time, for that I use:

`nx run-many --projects=api,ui --target=serve --parallel`

I tried appending the --ssl parameters to the run-many and the nestjs project failed to load. How can I pass these parameters to just the angular UI app ?

Comment: Not sure if you solved it, but this might prove helpful as it was to me: https://dev.to/nightbr/local-https-for-angular-app-in-nx-workspace-or-angular-cli-6ek

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution:**

```
nx serve YOUR_APP_NAME --ssl true
```